# Remove repeated words with suffix in a file

Tags: sort

I have a list of records in a file as in below example

```
word_word1
word_word1_acc
word_word2_acc
word_word3_acc
word_word4
```

I need to remove only `word_word1_acc` line in the file as it is only a repetition of the first line. As in the example, I have multiple fields in each line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed the exact file that you want to change, you can do

```
sed -i.old -e 's/word_word1_//' /path/to/filename
```

to change the file in-place. You can skip the `-i...` part to see what sed *would* do.

(The `-i` option tells sed to write a backup file of your source and append a `.old` to the filename)